# Create EXE output from a C project in NetBeans on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, netbeans, build, exe

I'm new to NetBeans.
I am using NB on my PC.
I just cleaned & built a project and the output was:

```
CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
```

Now I can't seem to find any executable.
How do I set the IDE to create an EXE file output from the project?

**Update** - Please read my comment bellow.

Comment: can you post your makefile please?

Comment: It's long but here you go: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Lmh7yLVj, What I'm trying to do (I am a .NET dev trying to do some C work) is compiling [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org "FFmpeg"), the I will try to update [this](http://code.google.com/p/amv-codec-tools/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FAMVmuxer%2Fffmpeg "AMV Codec Tools for FFmpeg") outdated project with the new up-to-date FFmpeg source, I hope I don't spend my time on something inachievable. I will appreciate any help in this aspect, which is the reason of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-read the instructions of that project (FFmpeg), and I had to `configure` it first using `./configure` in `msys` shell.

As per building ffmpeg with amv-codec-tools, that's simple:

1. Install MinGW + MSYS and add environment vars for their bin folders
2. Checkout the latest revision of amv-codec-tools to the `msys\home` folder
3. Remove the folder `amv-codec-tools\AMVMuxer\ffmpeg`
4. Checkout the latest revision of FFmpeg to `amv-codec-tools\AMVMuxer\ffmpeg` instead the previous ver.
5. Open the MSYS shell
6. Navigate to amv-codec-tools\AMVMuxer (`cd /home/amv-codec-tools/amvmuxer`)
7. Run `make build`

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Press F6 or Shift F6 for project main file.

Also if you are coding Java(NetBeans) then you must create a main method in the class.

EDIT: The file is available under $Projects -> $Projectname -> Debug || Release -> debug.exe || *.exe

Comment: **THAT DOESN'T WORK.** It shows me this dialog: http://i.imgur.com/SgCH1.png, please read my comment on the question. Also, to mention again, it's a C project.

Answer (score 1):

After you build, the executable should be in a path like PROJECT/dist/PLATFORM/project.exe (dist or  build can't remember exactly)

Comment: `dist\Default\MinGW-Windows\package` is the only path and it contains no files :( please read my comment on my original question.

Comment: If you're using MinGW try to compile via `make build` in Msys. The Makefile might not be NB-compatible or not set up correctly.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to find it? I'm completely new to NetBeans and to C at all.

Comment: Do you have Msys and MinGW installed? If yes open Msys console, cd to project dir and run `make build` (or whatever make task name that builds depending on Makefile)

Comment: But NetBeans Make is configured to MSYS's make (`C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe`)

Comment: Did you do what I said? Need to do that manually because NB as I see, runs `make all` and Makefile has no such task `make: Nothing to be done for `all'.` in the output.

Comment: So maybe I can add some content to the Makefil? Or perhaps changing NB' s settings or its Make arguments?

Comment: Let's see if it works in the console first. The task is usually named "build" but can differ. Please run `make build` in Msys console ...

Comment: Found it. I had to `configure` it first. I found the info in the `INSTALL` file of FFmpeg ([Source](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/config-mak-td934399.html))